# Expressions inside 'source' prop of <Image> component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In React Native, I can do

```
<Image
  source={
    require(<image uri>)
  }
/>
```

and I can use the ternary operator like this

```
<Image
  source={
    true ? require(<image uri>) : require(<other image uri>)
  }
/>
```

but I can't, for example, do this

```
<Image
  source={
    if (true) {
      require(<image uri>)
    }
  }
/>
```

In fact, my code editor (VsCode) greys out the 'true' keyword. It's clear that I can't use expressions like this in the 'source' field, but can anyone give me an explanation of what exactly the rule is here? Is it as simple as that? Or can you point me to any resources that dig into the specification on this?

Comment: You can in fact use expressions, but `if () ...` isn't an expression. JSX doesn't support statements and the like, but you can do all that in the `render()` method, before returning the JSX. (to be clear: an expression is anything that evaluates into a single int / object / text / etc.)

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for your quick reply, and for your clarification on the difference between expressions and statements. To be clear, it's just JSX in general that doesn't support statements anywhere? And "if () ..." is a statement whereas " x ? y : z " is an expression, which JSX does support, is that right?

Comment: @gkeenley that is sort of correct, but it's not specific to JSX. A statement (which is universally preceded by a keyword such as `if`, `return`, `try`, `switch` etc) can never be used where a value is expected. For example, `x ? return y: return z` is invalid because `return` is a statement and the ternary operator expects a value. Another example might me `function(if(x){ val1 } else { val2 }  )`. Since a function statement expects a value, this is invalid. Since JSX brackets expect a value, they only accept expressions and not statements. Hope that helps clear it up!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var bShow = true or false
<Image
  source={
    true && require(<image uri>)
  }
/>
```